# Looking for faults in algorithm for organizing a one-way railway station traffic

Tags: c, algorithm, stack

I wrote the code below for solving [this railway station traffic programming contest question](http://poj.org/problem?id=1363). ( You may read comments and proposed solutions [here](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=E22mCwAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&hl=pt-BR&pg=PA146#v=onepage&q&f=false)). However, there are a few exceptional cases for which this code won't work. What are they?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
    int n, i,j;
    int * array;
    scanf("%i",&n);
    array = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
    for(i=0;i<n;++i) scanf("%i",&array[i]);
    for(i=0;i<n;++i){
        if(i+1 == array[i]) array[i] = -1;
        else{
            if(array[i] < i+1){
                for(j=0;j<i;++j){
                    if(array[i] == j+1){
                        if(array[j] == -1){
                            printf("No\n");
                            return 0;
                        }
                        else array[i] = array[j] = -1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;++i) if(array[i] != -1) break;
    if(i == n) printf("Yes\n");
    else printf("No\n");
    return 0;
}
```

P.S.: I'm assuming this program takes one entry at each time ( rather than waiting for an 0 for signaling the end of input ).

**What this code is supposed to do:**

1) I'm assuming you've already read [what's in this link](http://poj.org/problem?id=1363).

2) After copying a sequence into an array, we must verify whether or not this sequence is valid.

So we use the following algorithm:

1. Iterate over the sequence, starting from the first element.
2. If element = element's index + 1 ( because C lists are zero-indexed ), then element = -1.
3. Otherwise, if and only if element < element's index: We look for a previous element for which ( current  element == previous' element index + 1 ) is valid. If this element is found, then now both current element and previous element are changed to -1. If previous element has already been changed before ( that is, it's already -1 ) then this is not a valid sequence.
4. If after iterating over the list like this any elements are still left, this is not a valid sequence.

Examples:

> **Example 1**
>
> Array: 5 4 3 2 1
>
> 5 : 5 > 0 + 1, skip. 4: 4 > 1 + 1, skip. 3: 3 == 2 + 1. Then 3 -> -1.
>
> Array: 5 4 -1 2 1
>
> 2 : 2 < 3 + 1. 4 has an index of 1 and 1 + 1 = 2.
>
> Array: 5 -1 -1 -1 1
>
> 1: 1 < 4 + 1. 5 has an index of 0 and 0 + 1 = 1.
>
> Array: -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
>
> Therefore this sequence is valid.
>
> **Example 2**
>
> Array: 5 4 1 2 3
>
> 5: 5 > 0 + 1, skip. 4: 4 > 1 + 1, skip. 1: 1 < 2 + 1. 5 has an index
>   of 0.
>
> Array: -1 4 -1 2 3
>
> 2: 2 < 3 + 1. 4 has an index of 1.
>
> Array: -1 -1 -1 -1 3
>
> 3: 3 < 4 + 1. -1 ( at position 2 ) has an index of 2. 2 + 1 = 3.
>   Therefore the sequence is not valid.

Comment: A good start would be to use meaningful variable names

Comment: And comments. Not *obvious* comments like "set a to 0" for `a = 0;`, but comments that tells us about the algorithm used, why it was chosen, how it is supposed to work, anything that can not be figured out by a beginner reading the code. In fact, explaining the algorithm and the code for someone else (like all of us here) might help *you* understand it better. [Rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) is a very useful technique.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - You mean some narative

Comment: @EdHeal Perhaps. For this case I would think something like that might help the OP figure out what the corner cases might be.

Comment: Alright, I'll fix that and give some examples in a couple of minutes.

Comment: Done. Now I guess it's well-explained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of an input where your code will give the wrong output:

```
5
3 4 2 5 1
```

Your description gave a translation of the code in English, but did not give insight into why that algorithm would solve the problem. So, I just went for a solution where an extra array is used for keeping track of the carriages that are in the station, which will have to function like a stack (First-in-last-out):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
    int n, i;
    int carriageAtA = 1;
    int * array;
    int * station;
    int stationSize = 0;
    // Read input
    scanf("%i",&n);
    array = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
    station = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
    for(i=0;i<n;++i) scanf("%i",&array[i]);
    // Iterate the desired carriages in sequence
    for(i=0;i<n;++i) {
        // While the last one in the station is not what we need:
        while ((!stationSize || station[stationSize-1] != array[i]) && carriageAtA <= n) {
            printf("Move %i from A to station\n", carriageAtA);
            // Last carriage in station B is not what we need, so pull one in from A:
            station[stationSize] = carriageAtA;
            stationSize++; // There is now one more carriage in the station
            carriageAtA++; // This is the next carriage at A
        }
        if (!stationSize || station[stationSize-1] != array[i]) {
            // Could not find desired carriage at A nor at station. Give up.
            printf("No\n");
            return 0;
        }
        // Drive last carriage at station to B:
        printf("Move %i from station to B\n", array[i]);
        stationSize--;
    }
    printf("Yes\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The additional `printf` calls are just for getting a view of the process. Remove them when you are satisfied.